# Deriving the first homology group of the circle using cubical sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Massey's textbook, the first homology group is defined as the quotient group:

$$H_1(S^1) = Z_1(S^1)/B_1(S^1)$$

where $Z_1(S^1)$ is the subgroup generated by all non-degenerate curves which have no boundary, and $B_1(S^1)$ is the subgroup generated by all non-degenerate curves which are the boundary of some surface in our space.

In this particular case, since $S^1$ is one dimensional, would I be right in saying that $B_1(S^1)$ is empty? Then $H_1(S^1) = Z_1(S^1)$. But I can't see why $Z_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$? Intuitively, I know that the fundamental group of the circle $\pi_1(S^1,x_0) = \mathbb{Z}$, but the fundamental group talks about loops centered at some base point $x_0$, but the first homology group doesn't have any basepoint specified? Further, any two loops that travel once around the circle clockwise are homotopic, and are hence represented by the 'same element' in $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)$, but I can't see how they are equivalent in $Z_1(S^1)$?

Comment: Can you remind us what "non-degenerate" means in this setting? It is assumption I generally don't see when defining singular homology.

Comment: Massey bases everything off 'n-cubes' instead of simplicial sets, and an n-cube is just a continuous mapping from $I^n$ to your space $X$. In this sense, an n-cube would be degenerate if the mapping doesn't depend on at least one of the variables (i.e. it actually represents a k-cube where k < n)

Comment: $Z_1$ is gigantic. Try to find the square whose boundary shows that subdividing the circle into two arcs is equal to the class given by tracing out the whole circle, as one example of a nontrivial class in $B_1$. $C_n$ is nonempty for all $n$; "nondegenerate" is not that strong a condition.